# How to call Cross domain API in C#

Tags: c#, cors, preflight

I need to call a API of different server using C#.
I am using following method

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "tolen");
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync("url");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
}
```

but it always give

> 403 forbidden

I have asked the developer of this API and he suggested that I need to send **preflight request** also.

Comment: is the service you are calling is also in C# ?

Comment: The developer of the external domain will have to set their API up to allow CORS. The pre-flight request is just checking to see if this request is allowed by the external API. (  app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); )

Comment: CORS is allowed as it is accessible from browser(Jquery). So can we create a pre-flight request in c#?

Answer (score 0):

if your service code written in c# then you can enable cross domain access in api method section like below

```
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public string Get()
        {
```

above code enable cors for all external domain but you can specify only your own domain by this way

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://yourdomain.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

useful two links https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx